# How to force Fedora 27 to write to USB flash drive immediately?

Tags: fedora, usb, cp, usb-drive, write

My Fedora 27 writes actual data to USB on `umount`. Before `umount` it works only with links or something like that. So, for example, when I transfer a big file of 5 GB `cp /home/iam/bigFile /run/mnt/iam/myUSB/` it will be transferred in several seconds. But there are no actual writes. After I use `umount /dev/sdd1` it will be unmounting the USB for several minutes. 
If I remove the USB after `cp /home/iam/bigFile /run/mnt/iam/myUSB/` but before `umount /dev/sdd1` the file will be corrupted.
How to force Fedora to write real data when I use `cp`?

Comment: I haven’t tried, but I wonder if mounting it with the sync flag would help.

Answer (score 0):

After copying the files, run `sudo sync -f one/of/the/files`. It will write all the filesystem cached data where that file is stored immediately. Read the man page for some regards on file systems.

Comment: Is it possible to configure sync by default? So, that all data I place to flash drives are written immediately?

Comment: You'd need to mount it with a write through option. I can't look into the details right now, but you should be able to find it with a simple internet search...

Comment: Oh, @Jeff Schaller seems to have commented just that on your question...